# Sublime text changing from biber to bibtex upon error

Tags: biber, sublime-text, latextools

I am using Sublime Text 3 with LatexTools and Texlive. If, after compiling with biber I get an error due to an undefined citation, the next compile runs automatically with bibtex instead, in which case all citations are wrong.

MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{test-bib.bib}
@article{test,
  author                 = {A. Author},
  title                  = {Paper},
  year                   = {2023},
  journal                = {Journal},
  number                 = {1},
  pages                  = {1-10},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test-bib.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{test}
\cite{bibid}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Compiling this once with Ctrl+B runs pdflatex, biber, pdflatex, pdflatex and gives the error:

```
Package biblatex Warning: The following entry could not be found(biblatex)                in the database:(biblatex)                bibid(biblatex)                Please verify the spelling and rerun(biblatex)                LaTeX afterwards.
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'bibid' on page 1 undefined on input line 18.
```

Immediately compiling again with Ctrl+B runs pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex and gives the error:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'test' on page 1 undefined on input line 17.
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'bibid' on page 1 undefined on input line 18.
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 20.
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex)                test_bib(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

Compiling again reruns with biber and cycles through the two options.

The expected output should instead be the error:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'bibid' on page 1 undefined on input line 18.
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex)                test_bib(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

and that pressing Ctrl+B would rerun with biber.

I have tried both the traditional, basic and simple builders - they all give this result.

How do I fix this? Alternatively, is there a way of forcing a compile with biber?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it stands there are potential pitfalls with all of the simple/traditional/basic builders in [LaTeXTools](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/)

The [simple builder](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/blob/b27fc391b2e0c7298d7e2be2472f3642e25ed3d2/builders/simpleBuilder.py) always runs `bibtex`. This cannot be used with `biber` and will mess up any previous `biber` compilations.

The [traditional builder](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/blob/b27fc391b2e0c7298d7e2be2472f3642e25ed3d2/builders/traditionalBuilder.py) runs `texify` if it detects MiKTeX on Windows, otherwise it uses `latexmk`.  I believe `texify` will only ever compile `bibtex`, however `latexmk` should reliably auto-compile `biber`.

The [basic builer](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/blob/b27fc391b2e0c7298d7e2be2472f3642e25ed3d2/builders/basicBuilder.py) (which seems the most complex as it tries to manage everything itself) will run `bibtex` or `biber` as long as there is a citation undefined warning in the log.
Unfortunately it will run `bibtex` unless the log file explicitly contains a warning from [`biblatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) to rerun `biber`, which is not sufficient.

In your example, after `biber` has been run, it places in the `.bbl` file a note that the reference `bibid` was missing from the supplied bib files, so [`biblatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) just logs the citation as not found, it knows `biber` has been run and failed to find the log file so just re-running `biber` won't help.
Then, finding a "citation undefined" warning but this time no "(re)run biber" warning, the basic builder executes `bibtex` which breaks the bibliography, but returns the "(re)run biber" notice, hence the return to running `biber` on the subsequent compilation.

Obviously you can just run `biber` on the command line as necessary, but all three of the builders will try and fix any undefined citation errors, which is liable to trigger a `bibtex` run, breaking the bibliography.

https://latextools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/available-builders/#script-builder seems to allow you to provide your own set of compilation instructions which would appear to allow you to set a compilation that always run `pdflatex` then `biber` then `pdlfatex`.